# SQL: Oracle avg over group

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I would like to show my problem on example.
So, I have students, they are studying in different schools and I would like to count average by schools and then count total average.

Example:

[image: example]

So, how could i get result like this one?

Thanks in advance!

One more option - it is really much more comfortable for me to do this in one query.

Comment: See analytic functions https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions001.htm#i81407

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @tamasRev I've tried to use avg("schoolAvg")over(), different cases of partition by but that does not help.

Comment: @tamasRev I've got 2 variants of mistakes: 
Either it counts average by each row (even duplicates) on skips different schools with same average if I use "avg(distinct ..)

Comment: Two questions... do you want the OUTPUT to show one row for each student, or only one row per school? And ... it seems you want to compute the "global" average by adding the school averages and dividing by the number of schools - is that what you want/need? ARE YOU SURE? That is a completely meaningless way to compute an "average"; a "global" average should be a WEIGHTED average of the school-by-school averages, weighted by number of students per school (which then is the same as computing the average for the entire table from the beginning, regardless of the "school" column).

Comment: @mathguy it's just an example to show that I need to count avg over other avg. I agree that here it is meaningless. I want to show one row per student (do not hide any fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with
     marks ( school, student, mark ) as (
       select 'School 1', 'James' , 5 from dual union all
       select 'School 1', 'Mark'  , 4 from dual union all
       select 'School 1', 'Howard', 5 from dual union all
       select 'School 4', 'Jho'   , 4 from dual union all
       select 'School 5', 'Kate'  , 5 from dual
     ),
     a ( school, s_avg ) as (
       select   school, avg(mark) 
       from     marks
       group by school
     )
select school, student, mark,
       avg(mark) over (partition by school) as avg_by_school,
       (select avg(s_avg) from a) as global_avg
from   marks;


SCHOOL   STUDENT       MARK AVG_BY_SCHOOL GLOBAL_AVG
-------- ------- ---------- ------------- ----------
School 1 James            5         4.667      4.556
School 1 Mark             4         4.667      4.556
School 1 Howard           5         4.667      4.556
School 4 Jho              4         4.000      4.556
School 5 Kate             5         5.000      4.556

5 rows selected.
```